# Woher stammt die Redensart: Da liegt der Hase im Pfeffer?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, german-to-english

a) Woher stammt die Redensart: Da liegt der Hase im Pfeffer?

b) was ist damit gemeint?

c) was wäre sinngemäss die Übersetzung auf Englisch?

Comment: Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass die Redensart etwas mit dem beliebten Gericht [Hasenpfeffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasenpfeffer) zu tun hat.

Comment: aber sicher tut sie das ;)

Comment: Eine passende Englische Übersetzung wäre möglicherweise: _"That's the real source of the problem."_, hat aber nicht die Nonchalance und den Witz. Ist eher dröge und trocken im Vergleich.

Comment: ja, die Bedeutung ist in beiden Sprachen klar, Schön wäre es einen ähnlichen blumigen und auch "historischen" Ausdruck im Englischen zu finden.

Comment: Like @πάνταῥεῖ sys, it means "that is the culprit", but the translation doesn't sound so, er, juicy. Perhaps the Shakespearian "therein lies the rub" catches some of it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis besonders denkt man an "rabbit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mit *Pfeffer* bezeichnete man früher nicht nur das Gewürz an sich, sondern auch damit und daraus zubereitete Gerichte - erhalten hat sich der [Hasenpfeffer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasenpfeffer), ein stark gewürztes Ragout aus Hasenfleisch.

Das macht es offensichtlich, dass mit der Redensart wohl ein Pfeffer (ein Ragout) gemeint war, in dem der "Hase" (also das Fleisch) möglicherweise aufgrund seiner Knappheit schwer zu finden war.

Adelung schreibt dazu

> Im Oberdeutschen wird auch eine stark mit Pfeffer gewürzte Brühe, eine Pfefferbrühe, der Pfeffer genannt. Einen Hasen in Pfeffer einmachen, ihn mit einer Pfefferbrühe zurichten. Daher die figürliche Redensart da liegt der Hase im Pfeffer, das ist der wahre Grund des Übels, daran liegt es, daran fehlt es.

Der Brite würde wohl etwas eher hasenfernes und baumstumpf- oder reibungsnahes sagen, wie *That's the snag* oder *There's the rub*.

Wenn wir schon bei fremden Sprachen sind: Das Französische (*c'est là que gît le lièvre*) und Niederländische (*Daar ligt de haas in het zout*) kennen beide eine fast wörtliche Übersetzung der Redensart. [Deutsches Sprichwörterlexikon von K. F. W. Wander (1867 ff.)]

Comment: die Briten haben doch Erfahrung mit der Jagd nach Wild, da müsste doch was äquivalentes zu finden sein, wie z.B: da sitzt der Fuchs im Bau! oder so ...

Comment: Erstaunlich und vergnüglich ist, dass genau da, wo der *Hase im Pfeffer liegt* auch der *Hund begraben liegt* (hoffentlich ist er nicht im Ragout gelandet...)

Comment: jetzt hast du mir die nächste Frage vemasselt :) aber die Frage wurde sicher schon diskutiert ...

Comment: "Wenn wir schon bei fremden Sprachen sind: Das Französische und Niederländische kennen beide eine fast wörtliche Übersetzung der Redensart." Kannst du uns das hier verraten?

Comment: Na, wenn du so nett fragst...

Comment: Den *Hund* bitte *begraben* lassen, und keinen Fall zum *Hasen* in den *Pfeffer* tun: In der *Pfanne* wird er nämlich *verrückt*.

Comment: Der Versuch eine Knappheit in die Redensart zu dichten um ein "schwer zu finden" zu begründen darf als gescheitert gelten.

Answer (score 1):

aus meinem Tagebuch vom 19. Februar 1961:

> Da liegt der Hase im Pfeffer

"So sagt man, wenn man meint: **"Und damit kommen wir nun zum Kernproblem, zur Hauptsache!"**

Im Mittelalter spielte als Gewürz der Pfeffer eine ganz besondere Rolle, wie er ja auch vielen Repten, obgleich sie auch andere Gewürze in Fülle enthielten, den Namen gab: Pfeffernüsse, Pfefferkuchen u.s.w.

Ein Hasenpfeffer nun, das ist eine gute, stark gewürzte Brühe, in der der Hase gesotten wurde. Obwohl man meinen sollte, dass der Hase am meisten interessierte, wird auch die schmackhafte Hasenbrühe, der  man gut Pfeffer beigemischt hat, sehr geschätzt."

Comment: (Soweit der Eintrag aus meinem Tagebuch vor 57 Jahren).  Zur Betonung des Pfeffers und der Bedeutung des letzten Satzes - da denke ich mir heute: Hasen gab es damals ja wie Sand am Meer, nur der Pfeffer war noch rar.)

Die Palme aber gewinnt natürlich tofro.

Comment: Oh, 1961 :-O. Da flog ich noch mit den Mücken, von Tagebuch schreiben ganz zu Schweigen. Wie gesagt, schön Dich in dieser Community zu haben.